# All you can put in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hello Android Lovers,

Having gone through various topics in the official technical materials (i.e. training, API reference, etc) on the Android website I have become quite interested in AndroidManifest.xml itself.

As you know, the approach that the topics take is that concepts are introduced little by little and then are followed by recommended ways of implementation by adding so and so  lines in Java code and by placing so and so elements+attributes in AndroidManifest.xml.

While there is a complete reference to the Android-specific Java API, I have been unable to find any such reference to the complete list of all elements and attributes, along with descriptions, ever to be put in the manifest file.

Please let me know if any official resource does exist that comprehensively lists down elements and attributes for AndroidManifest.xml.

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html.

Comment: Thanks. I needed this link that you provided:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Well... in my humble opinion, the real question should be what you do NOT have to put in AndroidManifest!
As you know, every Android app must have its own AndroidManifest file. This is needed to let Android to have the right information (e.g. API Level, permissions, activities, services, etc...) in order to properly run the app.

Some useful links:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

The basic elements of the AndroidManifest, however, are listed below.

## API Level (uses-sdk):

Here you can specify the API Level your app requires - i.e. the compatibility of the app with the various Android platforms. For example:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

In the example, API Level 8 indicates *Android 2.2.x (FroYo)*, while 17 indicates *Android 4.2.x (Jelly Bean)*.

The *android:minSdkVersion* attribute is required, while *android:targetSdkVersion* is optional (is set to the *android:minSdkVersion* by default).

You can find more on: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html.

## Permissions:

Here you can specify which permission your app needs. One can require an existing Android permission using the *uses-permission* element, or define a custom one using the *permission* element. Every permission is identified by a unique label. For example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Please, note that one should NEVER require more permissions than the ones needed! (ALWAYS check if your app really needs all the permissions in the AndroidManifest before releasing it...)

You can find more on:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

## Activities, Providers, Receivers and Services:

The last main elements of the AndroidManifest are related to declaring the various activities, providers, receivers and services of your app.

You can find more on:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response. I needed especially this link that you provided beside other ones:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html